# One-to-One Relationship Not Loading All Entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I have a (contrived and over-simplified, due to contractual constraints) data model that should look like this:

```
public class ProvisionalData
{
    public int ProvisionalDataID { get; set; }
    public string Data { get; set; }

    public Lot Lot { get; set; }
}

public class Destination 
{
    public int DestinationID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class LotDestination
{
    public int LotDestinationID { get; set; }
    public int DestinationID { get; set; }
    public DateTime Month { get; set; }

    public Destination Destination { get; set; }
}

public class Lot
{
    public int LotID { get; set; }
    public int ProvisionalDataID { get; set; }
    public int LotDestinationID { get; set; }


    public ProvisionalData ProvisionalData { get; set; }
    public LotDestination LotDestination { get; set; }
}
```

The relationship from Lot to ProvisionalData is a required one-to-one on both sides.  Please note, this is not the whole model, nor is the domain the concern.  The concern is with configuring the one-to-one relationship.

My relevant to the one-to-one mapping fluent configurations:

```
public class LotConfig : EntityTypeConfiguration<Lot>
{
    public LotConfig()
    {
        ToTable("Lot");
        HasKey(x => x.LotID);

        HasRequired(x => x.ProvisionalData)
            .WithRequiredDependent(x => x.Lot)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
    }
}


public class ProvisionalDataConfig : EntityTypeConfiguration<ProvisionalData>
{
    public ProvisionalDataConfig()
    {
        ToTable("ProvisionalData");
        HasKey(x => x.ProvisionalDataID);
    }
}
```

The other relationships shown are in fact set up - I have verified that they are being configured in my context, and all IDbSets exist and function correctly.  In fact, everything "works" with this setup, except that some ProvisionalData entities on navigation properties are not populated by the following query:

```
var lotDestination = db.lotDestinations
    .Where(x => x.DestinationId == destinationId && x.Month == month)
    .Include(x => x.Lots)
    .Include("Lots.ProvisionalData")
    .Include(x => x.Destination)
    .SingleOrDefault();
```

In my real dataset, this query will return a destination with 30 Lots.  16 of those lots have their ProvisionalData navigation property loaded.  14 do not.  This problem persists when I manually loop through each Lot and `db.Entry(lot).Reference(ProvisionalData).Load()`.  When I examine those entries, all 30 return `true` for `.IsLoaded`.  The query and `.Includes` appears to be doing what they are supposed to, but some of the entities aren't coming back for reasons I don't understand.  I'm hoping it's something simple that I can't see because I've been staring at it for too long.

However, when I change the relationship (ignoring existing database constraints) to a one-to-many with ProvisionalData entities looking like this:

```
public class ProvisionalData
{
public int ProvisionalDataID { get; set; }
public string Data { get; set; }

public IList<Lot> Lots { get; set; }
}
```

and a new Lot configuration like this:

```
public class LotConfig : EntityTypeConfiguration<Lot>
{
    public LotConfig()
    {
        ToTable("Lot");
        HasKey(x => x.LotID);

        HasRequired(x => x.ProvisionalData)
            .WithMany(x => x.Lots)
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.ProvisionalDataID);
    }
}
```

everything works flawlessly.  The only drawback here is that this doesn't reflect the true constraints in the database, so you could technically try to add multiple Lots to the same piece of ProvisionalData, which would break when trying to save.  I can build the logic in to prevent this myself, but why can't I express it here in Entity Framework?  Is my configuration incorrect?

Also interestingly, when I switch the above-mentioned query around to this dumb version to test things (with the one-to-one mapping still in place in EF):

```
var quota = db.Lots
    .Where(l => l.LotDestination.DestinationID == destinationId && l.LotDestination.Month == m)
    .Include(x => x.ProvisionalData)
    .Include(x => x.LotDestination)
    .Include(x => x.LotDestination.Destination)
    .Select(x => x.LotDestination)
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

*all of the provisional data comes back, but some of the Destinations do not*.  This hints to me that it has something to do with including navigation properties multiple levels deep across a one-to-one.  Has anyone else experienced this behavior before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EF does not officially support 1:1 associations other than in shared primary key 1:1 association situations.

What you are doing is create 1:many's and trying to tell EF that it's really a 1:1.  The problem is, the db schema is really a 1:many schema and EF will have problems here.

If your requirement is 1:1, then you need to use a shared primary key (both entities have the same primary key), and one also treats it as a foreign key).

Comment: I should note that the database came first in our model, and that SQL Server recognizes the relationship as one-to-one when adding the appropriate constraints (which we have).  This seems like a reasonable alternative to using shared primary keys (whether or not it's a standard/accepted approach in the SQL world, I guess I don't know - that's more of a DBA question, but it was how we did it initially).  Do you know if this was a conscious design decision by the EF team?

Comment: @jgoeglein - EF does not support any kind of constraint, so that's why it requires the shared primary key.  It's the only way to guarantee (without constraints) that the model is enforced.  So yes, it was a conscious decision because of the lack of support for constraints.  Yes, it's reasonable, but unsupported.  You may be able to get away with this in EF6 by using a stored proc to back the model.  However, EF6 is still in beta and probably won't be released until the fall.  Although, on second thought, I guess I have no idea how EF will do joins with sproc backings..

Comment: Just to put a bow on this, it turns out that you don't **have** to use shared primary keys if you don't care about the relationship being bidirectional - you can setup a one-way association across the one-to-many without configuring the many side to give the illusion of the constraint: [link](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2011/05/01/associations-in-ef-4-1-code-first-part-5-one-to-one-foreign-key-associations.aspx)

Comment: @jgoeglein - while this may work, and give you the results you want without error, keep in mind that the ef model will still consider this a 1:many and you will have to be careful if you make changes not to trip over that.

Answer (score 0):

I am facing the problems before, Mine solution was using 1:many because if POCOA include POCOB

```
.Include(x => x.POCOA.POCOB)
```

really return the POCOB as a list, since we know it 100% return one record, then during getting the data, we can say a.SingleOrDefault();